# htaccess reditect if server returns 404

Tags: .htaccess

For example I have a page http://www.f1u.org/**en**/its-interesting/166-cricri. 
How to write rule: if that page exists - open it. 
If it returns 404, then redirect to http://www.f1u.org/its-interesting/166-cricri

Comment: possible duplicate of [.htaccess 404 redirect to php file](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5305630/htaccess-404-redirect-to-php-file)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It sounds like you want the apache server to look ahead to see if the current URL exists, if not, redirect them. I think you might be able to use [mod_rewrite](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_rewrite.html) to accomplish this.

My first stab at it would be something like:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{IS_SUBREQ} false
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !-U
RewriteRule /en(/.*) $1 [R,L]
```

I'll note that I haven't tried it so the syntax and effects could be slightly off, and you'd need to be careful that you don't put yourself into an infinite loop, or wind up with too many subrequests (as that could impact the performance of your server). But hopefully it'll give you a starting point to play with. Alternatively mod-rewrite could (depending on server permissions) let you invoke scripts to determine rewrites as well, which could be an option as well.

Answer (score 1):

use this line in `.htaccess` file

```
ErrorDocument 404$ http://www.f1u.org/its-interesting/166-cricri
```

Comment: No, you didn't understand. I don't want redirect only this URL. I need redirect all URLs like f1u.org/en***** if they return 404.